# Track arrays elements order

Tags: c#, algorithm

I think my code is self explaining.

```
public Town[] GetShortestDistanceBetweenTowns() {
    Town[] allTowns = getTowns();
    Town[] bestPath = allTowns;
    int bestDistance = CalculateDistance(bestPath);
    int newDistance = bestDistance;

    //shuffle allTowns array and look for best distance
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        MixArray(allTowns);
        newDistance = CalculateDistance(allTowns);

        if (newDistance < bestDistance) {
            bestPath = allTowns;
            bestDistance = newDistance;
        }
    }

    return bestPath;
}
```

The problem is when I use `MixArray(allTowns)` it is also changing order of my `bestPath` array. I want to keep only best order in this array. What can I do with that?

Comment: Well yes, you only have one array - you're assigning the value of `allTowns` (which is a reference) to `bestPath`... so the two variables refer to the same array. If you modify that array "via" one element, you will see that modification via the other. It's just the normal way that reference types work. Maybe you want to clone the array instead?

Comment: You also should take a look at [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for finding the shortest distance between a collection of objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Town` is a reference type, so `Town[] bestPath = allTowns;` means that `bestPath` will always match `allTowns`.  To copy, you can implement IClonable for your `Town` class, or simply add a copy function that creates a new `Town` with duplicated values.

Here's a great article on reference vs value types:
http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx